# CustomAction on uninstall where INSTALLLOCATION is set

Tags: c#, wix

I have a windows service and when its running it logs nested log files in the install location of the windows service. I'm attempting to write a custom action that will delete said files only on uninstall. However, when it runs I get a "INSTALLLOCATION is an invalid directory" error. I'm assuming I need to change when the custom action runs in the "After="?" clause but I'm not sure what it should be.

This is the current code for the .wxs file

```
<Binary Id="CustomActionEXE" SourceFile="$(var.MyApp.TargetDir)MyApp.CA.dll" />
<CustomAction Id="RemoveLogFilesCA" BinaryKey="CustomActionEXE" DllEntry="RemoveLogFiles" Execute="immediate" Return="check"/>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="RemoveLogFilesCA" After="RemoveFiles">
    (NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE) AND (REMOVE="ALL")
  </Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

And the custom action code

```
public class CustomActions
{
    [CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult RemoveLogFiles(Session session)
    {
        // Error here: "INSTALLLOCATION is an invalid directory", value not set when the custom action is being executed After="RemoveFiles"
        //string installLocation = session.GetTargetPath("INSTALLLOCATION");
        return ActionResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First I would suggest the log files are user data and 1) shouldn't be deleted on uninstall and 2) shouldn't be kept under ProgramFilesFolder. ProgramData would be a better place.

If you must recursively delete these files, don't reinvent the wheel with your own CA. Use [RemoveFolderEx Element (Util Extension)](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/removefolderex.html) instead.